# Using grep -v -A 1 to deselect also a previous line

Tags: grep

Using for example:

```
grep -A 1 'hello' filename.c
```

will return the lines and the previous line of any 'hello'-match in filename.c

But now I want to deselect instead, so I tried:

```
grep -v -A 1 'hello' filename.c
```

which doesn't work to my surprise (it just returns the full filename.c file)

First question: Why is this?
Second more important question: Is it possible with grep (or sed) to deselect previous and/or next lines, like I tried with grep and the -v combined with e.g. -A 1, -B 3 or -C 2? Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "deselect"?

Comment: Can you post some example data and what you like to get out of it.

Comment: With deselect I mean using the -v or the --invert-match option of grep which select non-matching lines

Comment: `-A 1` won't return the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {for (i=1;i<f-B;i++) print a[i];for (i=f+A+1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' B=2 A=1 s="pattern" file
```

Example:

```
cat file
one
two    # 2 before
three  # 1 before
four   # pattern
five   # 1 after
six
seven
eight
```

Remove two lines before and one line after pattern `four`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {for (i=1;i<f-B;i++) print a[i];for (i=f+A+1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' B=2 A=1 s="four" file
one
six
seven
eight
```

PS this works only with one hit of `pattern`, but with array it could add more.
Problem starts when group of data starts to overlap.

Comment: Hi, your solution does work for my situation. So thanks! Though I still would like to know why 'my' grep doesn't work. But thanks anyway for the awk solution, I am pragmatic.